# How print power as 2^5 without get result 25

Tags: google-sheets, printing

I try to get inside cell of google sheets

[image]

I try `2^5`, but it gives 25 or shows `2^5`.

How should it be done?

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. To do what you want , `Google Sheets` would have to support formatting characters as subscript/superscript; which, unfortunately, it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this formula in a cell:

```
=2&char(8309)
```

this is the result:
[image: potenza]

for `other values` ​​see the following table:

[image: table]

if your pc has a numeric keypad, you can also enter the values ​​manually. To enter a code, make sure Num Lock is on, press the ALT key, and type the `number` of that code (only the number) on the numeric keypad.

Comment: thanks, but how can one type fast (each time look for the code of soo much numbers, make google sheets unusable) a lot of numbers and powers such as 1343.21^56/221, 1247778^(56/221) etc.. on Mac that have a numeric keypad.

Comment: If you have to often enter powers, fractions, roots and other mathematical amenities, then you should build the equation in [google docs](https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/?hl=en) and copy and paste it into a sheet cell